# Tomcat fail to start due to Geotools Maven libraries: "SEVERE: A child container failed during start"

Tags: maven, tomcat, jersey, geotools

I`m running a jersey web application using Eclipse + Maven + Tomcat (8.5). 
When I try to add the geotools dependencies in the pom.xml Tomcat doesn`t start due to:  "SEVERE: A child container failed during start".
I would like to understand the reason of this error. Are the jar in geotools repositories corrupted?

Tomcat error:

> Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:waytorest' did not
>   find a matching property. Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   built:          Jul 6 2016 08:43:30 UTC Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   number:         8.5.4.0 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
>   Windows 10 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
>   Version:            10.0 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Architecture:          amd64 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_101-b13 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\m_deli02\Documents\Development\workspaceMasterProject.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\m_deli02\Documents\Development\workspaceMasterProject.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>   Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4 Sep 08, 2016
>   11:13:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   INFO: Command line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\m_deli02\Documents\Development\workspaceMasterProject.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>   Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\endorsed
>   Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: The
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Users\m_deli02\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\eclipse;;. Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9080"] Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52
>   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9009"] Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52
>   AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 774 ms Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Sep 08, 2016 11:13:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.8.5.4 Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child
>   container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/waytorest]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/waytorest]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@348149c3]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4831)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4963)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to initialize component
>   [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3f569107]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:701)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header
>   (bad signature)   at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)    at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)   at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
>     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
>     at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)  at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
>     ... 13 more
>
> Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[9005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
>     ... 11 more
>
> Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>   INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9080"] Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53
>   AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause INFO: Pausing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9009"] Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal INFO: Stopping
>   service Catalina Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9080"] Sep 08, 2016 11:13:53 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy INFO: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-9009"]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wayto</groupId>
    <artifactId>waytorest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>waytorest Jersey Webapp</name>
    <build>
        <finalName>waytorest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run the application using "mvn embedded-glassfish:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                    <app>C:/Users/m_deli02/Documents/Development/workspaceMasterProject/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</app>
                    <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-web</artifactId>
            <version>${glassfish.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
             <version>9.4-1202-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.goebl</groupId>
            <artifactId>simplify</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--Can`t add geotools libaries. Tomcat error in extract Jars-->

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>   


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
      <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net repository</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
          <id>osgeo</id>
          <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
          <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
      </repository>
      <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>boundless</id>
          <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
          <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
      </repository>      
    </repositories>


    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
        <glassfish.version>3.1.1</glassfish.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>15.1</geotools.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I removed the jitpack repository:

```
<repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
```

Then I manually deleted geotools files in the .m2 repository.

Run Maven clean and install and done! Tomcat started normally.